# Specific Reusable Content based on Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, publishing-site, publishing-page

**Is there any (SharePoint 2013) built-in mechanism to narrow down the available "reusable text/html" snippets?**

The functionality is described [here](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Use-reusable-content-867896d1-d2a9-41a0-8ec1-45ea17da3dd2).

For example I'd like to offer only a very specific subset of reusable html on a specific publishing page layout. While you can in fact define a category when creating new reusable content there is no way you can "filter" on that category.

```
<SharePoint:RichHtmlField [...] FieldName="PublishingPageContent" ReusableContentCategory="Job Advertisments" />
```

Something like that would be neat. So I could specify on my page layout which reusable content an editor of this page can actually add to this page.

What is your solution to this? Or do you show all reusable text/html snippets everywhere?

Comment: Perhaps try the Edit Mode Panel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822364(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: We are using Edit Mode Panels. However this is not the "snippet" I was looking for. I was refering to the reusable content list. I added a link to my posting.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If its reusable HTML, would a content editor webpart on the page layout work for you? You could have HTML on a text file and add it to the Content Editor webpart snippet.